# JQueryUI Button Styling Has Incorrect Positioning When Applied to Link Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

When using the JQuery UI `.button` function to style a link item, the position of link "button" is shifted upwards when viewed in any browser other than Chrome and Safari.  This is readily apparent in FireFox and IE, even when going to the JQuery demo page at http://jqueryui.com/demos/button.

I am aware that this is a [known issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5254) as listed in the JQuery bugs, but it doesn't currently show a resolution.

Has anyone found a viable workaround (either via JQuery or CSS) to mitigate this issue so that the "buttons" line up properly in all browsers?  I feel that this is an important issue as I have many forms that have a Submit button and Cancel link right next to each other.

```
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
  <a class="button" href="/Home">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I wasn't aware of this bug but it is indeed there when I tried it in firefox.  Since this seems to be a vertical align issue, one way to solve it would be to put the anchor in a parent element with `display:table` and assign  `display:table-cell` to the anchor.  This should center the anchor within the parent as a table cell's content would.  I modified the css in firefox and this fixed the problem on the jquery ui demo page:

[image]

Note that this won't work in IE7 because it doesn't support `display:table-cell`.  But should work in IE8+ and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a button with an onclick event that acts like an a tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow( location )
    {
        window.open( location );
    }
</script>

<button onclick="openWindow('\home')">Home</button>
```